# Composing best web page fetcher function by HttpClientHandler for C#

Tags: c#, http, web-scraping

The returned class as result:

```
 public class cs_HttpFetchResults
    {
        public bool blResultSuccess = false;
        public string srFetchBody = "";
        public string srFetchingFinalURL = "";
        public bool bl404 = false;
    }
```

The `HttpWebRequest` version:

```
    public static cs_HttpFetchResults func_fetch_Page(string srUrl, int irTimeOut = 60,
 string srRequestUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
 string srProxy = null, int irCustomEncoding = 0, bool blAutoDecode = true, bool blKeepAlive = true,
  string srIPandHost = null)
    {
        cs_HttpFetchResults mycs_HttpFetchResults = new cs_HttpFetchResults();

        mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchingFinalURL = srUrl;

        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        WebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(srUrl);
            request.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

            if (srProxy != null)
            {
                string srProxyHost = srProxy.Split(':')[0];
                int irProxyPort = Int32.Parse(srProxy.Split(':')[1]);
                System.Net.WebProxy my_awesomeproxy = new WebProxy(srProxyHost, irProxyPort);
                my_awesomeproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                request.Proxy = my_awesomeproxy;
            }
            else
            {
                request.Proxy = null;
            }

            request.ContinueTimeout = irTimeOut * 1000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = irTimeOut * 1000;
            request.Timeout = irTimeOut * 1000;
            request.UserAgent = srRequestUserAgent;
            request.KeepAlive = blKeepAlive;
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

            WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            using (response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strumien = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    Encoding myEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    string srContentType = "";

                    if (response.ContentType != null)
                    {
                        srContentType = response.ContentType;
                        if (srContentType.Contains(";"))
                        {
                            srContentType = srContentType.Split(';')[1];
                        }
                        srContentType = srContentType.Replace("charset=", "");
                        srContentType = func_Process_Html_Input(srContentType);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        myEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(srContentType);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        myEncoding = irCustomEncoding == 0 ? Encoding.UTF8
                                                         : Encoding.GetEncoding(irCustomEncoding);
                    }

                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strumien, myEncoding))
                    {
                        mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        if (blAutoDecode == true)
                        {
                            mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchBody = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchBody);
                        }
                        mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchingFinalURL = Return_Absolute_Url(response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString(), response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString());
                        mycs_HttpFetchResults.blResultSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (request != null)
                request.Abort();
            request = null;
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            if (E.Message.ToString().Contains("(404)"))
                mycs_HttpFetchResults.bl404 = true;

            csLogger.logCrawlingErrors("crawling failed url: " + srUrl, E);

        }
        finally
        {
            if (request != null)
                request.Abort();
            request = null;

            if (response != null)
                response.Close();
            response = null;
        }

        return mycs_HttpFetchResults;
    }
```

The `HttpClientHandler`:

```
    async public static Task<cs_HttpFetchResults> func_fetch_Page_New(string srUrl, int irTimeOut = 60,
  string srRequestUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
  string srProxy = null, int irCustomEncoding = 0, bool blAutoDecode = true, bool blKeepAlive = true,
  string srIPandHost = null)
    {
        cs_HttpFetchResults mycs_HttpFetchResults = new cs_HttpFetchResults();

        mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchingFinalURL = srUrl;

        try
        {
            using (HttpClientHandler myClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                myClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                myClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                myClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                if (srProxy != null)
                {
                    string srProxyHost = srProxy.Split(':')[0];
                    int irProxyPort = Int32.Parse(srProxy.Split(':')[1]);
                    System.Net.WebProxy my_awesomeproxy = new WebProxy(srProxyHost, irProxyPort);
                    my_awesomeproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                    myClientHandler.Proxy = my_awesomeproxy;
                    myClientHandler.UseProxy = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    myClientHandler.Proxy = null;
                    myClientHandler.UseProxy = false;
                }

                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(myClientHandler))
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, irTimeOut);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", srRequestUserAgent);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", srRequestUserAgent);

                    if (blKeepAlive == true)
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Clear();
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Add("Keep-Alive");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.Clear();
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
                    }

                    using (var vrResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(srUrl))
                    {
                        if (vrResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                        {
                            var contenttype = vrResponse?.Content?.Headers?.First(h => h.Key.Equals("Content-Type"));
                            string srContentType = contenttype?.Value?.First();

                            Encoding myEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                            if (srContentType != null)
                            {
                                if (srContentType.Contains(";"))
                                {
                                    srContentType = srContentType.Split(';')[1];
                                }
                                srContentType = srContentType.Replace("charset=", "");
                                srContentType = func_Process_Html_Input(srContentType);
                            }

                            try
                            {
                                myEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(srContentType);
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                myEncoding = irCustomEncoding == 0 ? Encoding.UTF8
                                                                 : Encoding.GetEncoding(irCustomEncoding);
                            }

                            var bytes = await vrResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                            mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchBody = myEncoding.GetString(bytes);
                            if (blAutoDecode == true)
                            {
                                mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchBody = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchBody);
                            }

                            string responseUri = vrResponse.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();

                            mycs_HttpFetchResults.srFetchingFinalURL = Return_Absolute_Url(responseUri, responseUri);
                            mycs_HttpFetchResults.blResultSuccess = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (vrResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                                mycs_HttpFetchResults.bl404 = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            if (E.Message.ToString().Contains("(404)"))
                mycs_HttpFetchResults.bl404 = true;

            csLogger.logCrawlingErrors("crawling failed url: " + srUrl, E);
        }

        return mycs_HttpFetchResults;
    }
```

Other helper methods:

```
public static string func_Process_Html_Input(string srHtmlInput)
    {
        srHtmlInput = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(srHtmlInput);
        srHtmlInput = Regex.Replace(srHtmlInput, @"(\s)\s+", "$1").Trim();
        srHtmlInput = srHtmlInput.Replace("&#39", "'");
        return srHtmlInput;
    }

    public static string Return_Absolute_Url(string srRelativeUrl, string srCrawledUrl, List<string> lstBannedExtensions = null, bool blIgnoreBaseUriHost = false, bool blDoNotRemoveDash = false)
    {

        srRelativeUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(srRelativeUrl);

        srRelativeUrl = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(srRelativeUrl);

        lstBannedExtensions = (lstBannedExtensions == null) ? new List<String>() : lstBannedExtensions;

        string srReturnUrl = "null";

        if (srRelativeUrl.Length > 0)
            if (srRelativeUrl[0] == '.')
                srRelativeUrl = srRelativeUrl.Substring(1);

        Uri baseUri = new Uri(srCrawledUrl);

        Uri NewUrl;

        bool blUriResult = Uri.TryCreate(baseUri, srRelativeUrl, out NewUrl);

        if (blUriResult == true)
        {
            if (NewUrl.AbsoluteUri.ToString().StartsWith("http") && (NewUrl.Host == baseUri.Host || blIgnoreBaseUriHost == true))
            {
                string srLastSegment = NewUrl.Segments[NewUrl.Segments.Length - 1].ToString();
                if (lstBannedExtensions.Where(pr => srLastSegment.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf(pr) != -1).Count<string>() == 0)
                {
                    srRelativeUrl = NewUrl.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                    if (srRelativeUrl.IndexOf("#") != -1 && blDoNotRemoveDash == false)
                    {
                        srRelativeUrl = srRelativeUrl.Substring(0, srRelativeUrl.IndexOf("#"));
                    }

                    srRelativeUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(srRelativeUrl);

                    srRelativeUrl = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(srRelativeUrl);

                    srReturnUrl = srRelativeUrl;
                }
            }
        }

        return srReturnUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You really need to follow [Microsoft's naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

What is even the point of prefixing your class names with "cs"? All you get is unreadable names, especially when you then name your variables "my(ClassName)", e.g. `mycs_HttpFetchResults`. Using the "my" prefix is something you should avoid as well.

Same with properties etc.: do not implement some version of an Hungarian notation.

---

`func_fetch_Page` has eight parameters. That's waaay too many. Instead, construct a class where each of those params is a property, and pass that class.

---

If you have an `if...else`, try to make your `if` "positive":

```
        if (srProxy == null)
        {
           // create srProxy
        }
        else
        {
           // whatever is necessary
        }
```

---

Split your methods into smaller ones. `func_fetch_Page` is 120 lines, you could for instance easily move the creation of `HttpWebRequest` to its own method. Think [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

---

Adding "New" to a method name -- as in `func_fetch_Page_New` -- is just bad, unless this is a temporary measure and you need to check whether your new method does the same as your old one. Why not call this one `FetchPageAsync`?

---

Don't name a method "Return(Something)", e.g. `Return_Absolute_Url`. Name it Get(Something)".

Comment: ty for suggestions. it seems like my most mistakes about naming. do functions looks solid? also passing a lot of parameters have any problem performance wise? Actually i would appreciate if you rename them. So i would see how they would look when properly named :)